# Ошибка при переносе данных из shapefile в Postgres django

Tags: django, shape, gis, spatial

Я пытаюсь импортировать shape-файл в базу данных Postgres с помощью django. При импорте возникают проблемы: данные в ячейках смещаются, текст ячейки может разорваться посередине и частично залезть в следующую ячейку. Из-за этого числовые поля начинают содержать пробелы и другие строковые символы. Причину такого поведения я не знаю и прошу помочь разобраться. Опишу свои действия пошагово.

Есть валидная таблица БД с геометрией (точка). Она задана в модели django gis и имеет поля типов AutoField, CharField, FloatField и PointField.

Я делаю экспорт в формат shape с помощью библиотеки shapefile.py, экспорт проходит успешно, слой открывается в ArcMap 10.1, данные выглядят как должны.

Далее я редактирую данные в какой-нибудь ячейке вручную в ArcMap - либо в атрибутивной таблице, либо передвигаю точку. Когда я нажимаю кнопку 'Save Edits' по неизвестной причине (я подозреваю, что в этом причина ошибок при импорте) во все ячейки добавляются пробелы и ячейки начинают выглядеть как с выравниванием по центру. Но данные остаются в нужных ячейках.

При импорте с помощью той же библиотеки shapefile.py возникает ошибка на 13-й строке: `Значение '1500 5.01400' должно быть числом с плавающей запятой.` Это значение в ячейке типа Double, и в таблице ArcGIS оно '50.14'.

Во время импорта я вывожу в консоль данные каждой ячейки, и начиная с 10-й записи вижу смещение данных, как описано в начале топика. К 13-й строке смещение в первый раз затрагивает ячейку типа Double, что приводит к ошибке. Данные в ячейках все однотипные, похожие. Я не вижу причины, по которой они могут самовольно перелезать в другие ячейки. И я не вижу, почему при редактировании атрибутов в ArcMap в ячейки добавляются пробелы.

```
Traceback:
File "C:\imp_shp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\imp_shp\import_data\views.py" in to_import
  80.         for item in shp_deserializer(f, jsonimport):
File "C:\imp_shp\import_data\imp_shp.py" in Deserializer
  175.     for obj in PythonDeserializer(object_list, **options):
File "C:\imp_shp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py" in Deserializer
  161.                 data[field.name] = field.to_python(field_value)
File "C:\imp_shp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  1817.                 params={'value': value},
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте импортировать шейп штатными средствами PgAdminIII.
[image: Postgis]

а насчет аттрибутов шейпа - не верьте данным, в них обязательно есть ошибки - проверяйте, редактируйте. возможно повторный экспорт данных из arcgis решит часть проблем, в общем, изучайте ваши данные.
Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо. Может быть, ошибка и в данных, но почему не на первой строчке, если данные однотипные и примерно одного размера? Стандартными средствами импортируется хорошо, но у пользователя не будет доступа к базе в pgAdmin, поэтому импорт должен происходить через мою программу на Django. Более того, если отредактировать shp-файл с помощью другой  программы (у меня QGis), то импорт проходит успешно. Мне интересно, почему именно при редактировании ArcGis'ом возникают ошибки.

Comment: Часто бывает проблема из-за разделителя целой и дробной части, бывает в таблице атрибутов оказываются непечатные символы, но тут импорт обычно совсем ломается, трудно сказать. Вообще если Arcgis испытывает трудности с шейпом, то в нем все-таки что-то не то, все же родной формат для него.